# Construct a joint probability mass function from marginals

Tags: probability, distributions, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

I want to construct a joint probability mass function from its marginals, under some constraints. I would like to understand if this is always possible. Below, I formalise this question in terms of existence of at least one solution of a linear system.

Let $Y,V, X$ be three discrete random variables. $Y$ has support $\{0,1\}$. $V$ has support $\mathcal{V}$ with cardinality $|\mathcal{V}|>1$.  $X$ has support $\mathcal{X}$ with cardinality $|\mathcal{X}|>1$.
$X$ is independent of $V$.
$\Pr(\cdot)$ denotes the probability mass function.
$\beta$ is some known real number.
$\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ are such that $X\beta+V$ can take positive and negative values.

Consider the following system $(*)$ with vector of unknowns $\Big(\Pr(V=v, Y=y| X=x): v\in \mathcal{V},y\in \{0,1\}, x\in \mathcal{X}\Big)$ of size $2\times |\mathcal{V}|\times |\mathcal{X}|$:
$$
(*) \quad \begin{aligned}
&(1) \quad \sum_{y\in \{0,1\}}\Pr(Y=y,V=v|X=x) =\Pr(V=v) \quad \forall v \in \mathcal{V},\forall x \in \mathcal{X},\\
&(2) \quad \sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} \Pr(Y=y, V=v|X=x)=\Pr(Y=y|X=x) \quad \forall y\in \{0,1\},\forall x \in \mathcal{X}\\
& -----------------------\\
&(3) \quad\sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} \Pr(Y=1, V=v|X=x) *(x\beta+v) \geq 0\quad \forall x \in \mathcal{X},\\
&(4) \quad\sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} \Pr(Y=0, V=v|X=x) *(x\beta+v)  \leq  0\quad \forall x \in \mathcal{X},\\
& -----------------------\\
&(5) \quad0\leq  \Pr( Y=y, V=v|X=x)\leq 1 \quad \forall (y,v,x) \in \{0,1\}\times \mathcal{V}\times \mathcal{X},\\
&(6) \quad  \sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}}\sum_{y\in \{0,1\}}\Pr(Y=y,V=v|X=x) =1\quad \forall x \in \mathcal{X}.
\end{aligned}
$$
**Question**: Show that $(*)$ has at least one solution.

**Note:** (1)-(2) restrict the marginals of $\Big(\Pr(V=v, Y=y| X=x): v\in \mathcal{V},y\in \{0,1\}, x\in \mathcal{X}\Big)$; (3)-(4) impose some inequalities; (5)-(6) ensure that $\Big(\Pr(V=v, Y=y| X=x): v\in \mathcal{V},y\in \{0,1\}, x\in \mathcal{X}\Big)$ is a proper probability mass function.

(6) is redundant because implied by (1).

The system is not separable across $x$ because of the independence between $V$ and $X$, which plays a role in constraint (1).